# Want to update the db with select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

This is what I have (after many revisions)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select.status").change(function () {
        var myid = $(this).attr("id");
        var mystatus = $("#" + myid).val();
        var dataString = 'id=' + myid,
            'status=' + mystatus;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "inc/editfields.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function () {
                $('#statusmsg').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1500, function () {
                    $('#statusmsg');
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, err, e) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And the select statements which get a unique Id from the db when they are grabbed.

```
<select class="status" id="status<? echo $id;?>">
<option value="Vrij"<? if ($regiodata["status"]=='Vrij') echo " selected";?>>Vrij</option>
<option value="Bezet"<? if ($regiodata["status"]=='Bezet') echo " selected";?>>Bezet</option>
<option value="Optie"<? if ($regiodata["status"]=='Optie') echo " selected";?>>Optie</option>
</select><div id="statusmsg"></div>
```

BUT, it does not work after hours and hours of trying all kind of things. Anyone can help me with is possibly wrong here? Before I pull out any more of my hair -:)

Comment: in your dataString... are you missing an ampersand or something? `var dataString = 'id='+ myid, 'status='+ mystatus;` should be `var dataString = 'id='+ myid + '&status='+ mystatus;`

Comment: What is in your php file? What are you trying to do? Populate from the select or update from select?

Comment: @PedroEstrada That's a syntax error, too. Need to concat the strings, the comma doesn't belong.

Comment: you should write your data field in your ajax call this way `data: { id : myid, status : mystatus }`

Comment: @JasonP Thanks for catching that, i updated my comment to reflect it

Answer (score 2):

```
    var dataString = 'id=' + myid,
        'status=' + mystatus;
```

should be:

```
var dataString = 'id=' + encodeURIComponent(myid) +
                 '&status=' + encodeURIComponent(mystatus);
```

But it would be better to do:

```
var dataString = { id: myId,
                   status: mystatus
                 };
```

When you use an object as the `data:` parameter to `jQuery.ajax()`, it will encode the parameters automatically.

Not related to the question, but:

```
$("#" + myid).val()
```

can be simplified to:

```
$(this).val()
```

or

```
this.value
```

Comment: Only the message does not show up where intended. Is there something wrong there as well?

Comment: The only weird thing I see is that the fadeIn completion function doesn't do anything. But I don't think that should prevent the fadeIn from working.

Comment: The final result is:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select.status").change(function(){
var getid = $(this).attr("id");
var myid=getid.replace("status","");
var mystatus = $(this).val();
var dataString = {id: myid, status: mystatus};
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
cache: false,
url:"inc/editfields.php",
data: dataString,
dataType:"html",
success: function(response) { $('#statusmsg'+ myid).html(response) .fadeIn('slow') .delay(3000) .fadeOut('slow'); },
error: function(xhr,err,e){ alert( "Error: " + err ); }
});
return false;
});
});
</script>

Comment: The only thing left is to deselect the listbox. Can't get that done. Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `$(document).focus()`